# How Flask Sqlalchemy db.query session works?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use flask-sqlalchemy, define a model:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    # define user model
    pass
```

When I use it as :

```
User.query.all()
```

how the session works?

does it need some code like session.close() or session.commit() somewhere?
thanks.

Comment: I read the source code ,model.query have associate a session, it's closed internal?

Comment: May be. I'm not quite understanding your question.

Comment: @HassanMehmood   i know  db.session not related to User.query.all(), but there is one session related with User.query, I want to known if there is some place to close or commit this session  in flask sqlalchemy internal

Answer (score 0):

When you **query** for object in flask sqlalchemy, you do not need to **commit**. If you are **inserting** or **editing** you do need to yes.

Just some query:

```
>>> User.query.limit(1).all()
[<User u'admin'>]
```

Inserting a new record:

```
>>> from yourapp import User
>>> me = User('admin', 'admin@example.com')
>>> db.session.add(me)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Comment: User.query does have one session, it starts a transaction when query, how Flask-Sqlalchemy handler this ?